# Const need to be const but I need to change the value 'died'

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

`Const` need to be `const` but I need to change the value `died`.

```
const person = {
    name: 'Bowie',
    died: 2012
}

person = {
    name: 'Bowie',
    died: 2016
}

console.log(person);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst you cannot replace the value of a `const` variable, if its value is an object you can still by default change the properties within that object.

```
const person = {
    name: 'Bowie',
    died: 2012
}

person.died = 2016;

console.log(person);
```

The exceptions are if the whole Object has been "frozen", or if the specific property has been set as unwritable.

Comment: Use `Object.freeze()` to make object immutable and avoid the properties to be changed

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:
 Here you can not assign a new object to `person` as it is a `const` but you can edit the existing object.

> The 'person' variable here holds the reference to the object and if
>   you change the contents of the object then you are not changing the
>   reference.

Hence no error with `const` like this.

`person.died = 2016`

Answer (score 0):

change it like the following

```
person['died'] = 1976
```

Answer (score 0):

The `const` declaration creates a read-only reference to a value. It does not mean the value it holds is immutable, just that the variable identifier cannot be reassigned. For instance, in the case where the content is an object, this means the object's contents (e.g., its parameters) **can be altered** .

Try this code:

```
const person = {
    name: 'Bowie',
    died: 2012
}

person.died= 2016;

console.log(person);
```